# Axios call api with GET become OPTIONS

Tags: javascript, symfony, cors, axios, preflight

I use axios for calling API (in front-end).
I use the method "GET" :

```
import axios from 'axios';
import querystring from 'querystring';

var url   = "mydomain.local",
    token = "blablabla...blabla";  

var configs = {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'Agency': 'demo0'
    }
};

var testapi = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://api.' + url
    });

testapi.get( '/relativeUrl', configs
).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

I got a 405 Method Not Allowed. The method is "OPTIONS" but I use the method ".get()".
[405 Method Not Allowed. Method OPTIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq8OL.png)

I test call api with postman and I get 200 OK :

[postman 200 OK screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAe6m.png)

Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: OPTIONS is a pre-flight request that checks if the server you GET/POST from, allows you to GET/POST at all. It's probably some config setting on the server that's blocking your GET.

Comment: In the Response headers, I got Access-Control-Allow-Origin:"*" and Allow:"GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE" so I think GET method is available.

Comment: Maybe try changing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin:" * "   to the actual origin. Not all browsers allow ACAO="*". But that would normally create a different error, so not sure. I'm sorry, out of other ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. ACAO="*" is working for : `testapi.post( '/login_check', querystring.stringify({
    _username: 'adherent0',
    _password: 'adherent0'
})` so I don't think this is the problem.
I think : `var configs = {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'Agency': 'demo0'
    }
};`
is the problem but I don't know what I doing wrong

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Like @Shilly says, OPTIONS method is pre-flight on modern browsers when [Preflighted requests conditions (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) :

In the response header I had `Allow:"GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE"`.
So `OPTIONS` method is not available and need to configure it on in the server (Apache).

I do the change on apache (*/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf*) :

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

In Request headers I have :

[image]

### Origin: "null" is a problem. The cause is :

> file:// URLs produce a null Origin which can't be authorized via
>   echo-back. Don't trying to perform a CORS request from a file:// URL ([see this post for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3744697/5380539))

### After put my javascript file on a apache server, the Origin was not null but I need to add NelmioCorsBundle to my Symfony project to allow preflight

Answer (score 0):

So the way to solve this `npm install qs`.

Then:

```
import qs from 'qs'

function send(params) {
  return axios.post('/api/create/', qs.stringify(params))
}
```