# Vue.js PATCH method not allowed

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, patch

Hi everyone POST and GET methods are working on my application, but PATCH method don't. On my WAMP server everything works fine. On VPS server - don't. I get 405 Method not allowed.

I am using: Laravel 5.4, Vue.js 2.

Patch method:

```
axios.patch('/profile/' + this.profile.id + '/update', this.overview)
.then(resp => {
    this.successDataSave(resp.data)
})
```

Route:

```
Route::patch('/profile/{profile}/update', 'AppController@update');
```

EDIT: PATCH method doesnt work only on axios, if I use patch route on html form, with {{ method_field('PATCH') }} it works.

Comment: see CORS preflight request : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137354/axios-call-api-with-get-become-options/42141696#42141696

Answer (score 2):

Using `{{ method_field('PATCH') }}` generates the following html:
    `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">`

So try set: `this.overview._method = "PUT"`

And then do a post:

```
axios.post('/profile/' + this.profile.id + '/update', this.overview)
    .then(resp => {
        this.successDataSave(resp.data)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your route with following route that use for all CRUD opration:

```
Route::resource('/profile', 'AppController@update');
```

and you can check the docs for more information

[resourceController](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers)